# How to get access tokens for accessing google drive in java?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm developing a j2ee application for upload and download the files from Google drive. I'm stuck on the process of getting the access tokens after authorization. How can a servlet handle sending request for access token to server?

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer link for Google Drive Rest API**

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: I needed a authentication to access the files. How to get access tokens for the authentication ?